# Using a full text index with PostgreSQL and Doctrine

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, orm

I received the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[54000]: Program limit exceeded: 7 ERROR:  index row size 2728 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index "fulltext"
DETAIL:  Index row references tuple (1,33) in relation "manual".
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing. (54000) class: PDOException
```

The table in question is:

```
\d manual
                                      Table "public.manual"
    Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |              Default
--------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id           | integer               |           | not null | nextval('manual_id_seq'::regclass)
 parent_id    | integer               |           |          |
 name         | character varying(45) |           | not null |
 content      | text                  |           |          |
 keywords     | text                  |           |          |
 listorder    | smallint              |           |          |
 display_list | boolean               |           |          |
Indexes:
    "manual_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "unique_name_manual" UNIQUE, btree (name)
    "fulltext" btree (keywords, name, content)
    "idx_10dbbec4727aca70" btree (parent_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_10dbbec4727aca70" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES manual(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "manual" CONSTRAINT "fk_10dbbec4727aca70" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES manual(id)
```

I thought I had a full text index per my Doctrine config `<index name="fulltext" columns="keywords, name, content" flags="fulltext"/>`, but it appears I don't.  Am I doing something wrong or is a Doctrine deficiency?  Recommended solutions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping https://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Manual" table="manual">
    <indexes>
      <index name="fulltext" columns="keywords, name, content" flags="fulltext"/>
    </indexes>
    <unique-constraints>
      <unique-constraint name="unique_name_manual" columns="name"/>
    </unique-constraints>
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="name" type="string" length="45" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="content" type="text" length="65535" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="keywords" type="text" length="65535" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="listorder" type="smallint" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="displayList" type="boolean" column="display_list" nullable="true"/>
    <one-to-many field="topics" target-entity="Manual" mapped-by="topic" fetch="LAZY"/>
    <many-to-one field="topic" target-entity="Manual" inversed-by="topics" fetch="LAZY">
      <join-column name="parent_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="true"/>
      <order-by>
          <order-by-field name="listorder" direction="ASC" />
      </order-by>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Your \d of the table does not show any full text search indexes, only default btree indexes.  I know nothing about Doctrine.  Is the section you list supposed to be creating the indexes, or describing to Doctrine what indexes already exist?

Comment: @jjanes  Agree, \d doesn't show, however, according to the documentation, `flags="fulltext"` should have added.

Comment: Could you link to that part of the docs?

Comment: @jjanes  I think I might have misquoted the docs.  I am fairly new to doctrine and must have seen it is some other answer or tutorial and took it for gospel.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fulltext flag only works with MySQL.